# Spring MVC + Hibernate encoding problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, encoding, spring-mvc

I work on Spring MVC + Hibernate application, use MySQL (ver. 5.0.51a) with the InnoDB engine.

The problem appears when I am sending a form with cyrillic characters.
As the result, database contains senseless chars in unknown encoding.

All the JSP pages, database (+ tables and fields) created using UTF-8.
Hibernate config also contains property which sets encoding to UTF-8.

I had solved this by creating filter which encodes request content with UTF-8.
Exemplary code:

```
…
encoding = "UTF-8";
request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
chain.doFilter(request, response);
…
```

But it visibly slows down the app.

The interesting thing is that executing insert query directly from the app (i.e. running from Eclipse as Java Application) works perfect.

**UPD.**

As far as I understood, using filter is the only working solution in my case.

I didn't know about standard CharacterEncodingFilter. Use it now, works very well!

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: changing the character encoding in the request object like this should *not* have a visible effect on speed of the application. something else must be going on

Comment: have you by any chance declared the `doFilter()` method to be `syncrhonized` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSP files must be UTF-8 in two ways:

- the header `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>`
- their content - `right-click > properties` in eclipse and make their encoding UTF-8 there (it may refuse to convert it, so *cut* the current content, change the encoding, and then paste it back)

Then spring has a [`CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) for this case, which shouldn't have any significant performance hit:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Actually, no filter should have a significant performance hit, unless its `doFilter()` method is declared `synchronized`.

Comment: @Bozko. I have UTF-8 in both the header and the pages. doFilter() method does not contain the keyword «synchronized». It seems like slowing down is just my subjective perception. CharacterEncodingFilter works fine! Thanks.

Comment: -1 for "If this doesn't work". If your pages are not `ISO-8859-1` (at browser side), you MUST use `CharacterEncodingFilter` for correct processing of non-us-ascii input (unless your servlet container violates the servlet spec here, like Jetty).

Comment: @axtavt I fixed that tiny detail.

Comment: so the filter will convert posted form values or?

Answer (score 2):

It's your price for doing the correct encoding transformation: UTF-8 (request)-> UTF-16 (Java) -> UTF-8 (DB).

I would be surprised though if it (transformation) took more than a few percent of overall request time. If it does, something is done wrong IMHO.

> All the JSP pages ... created using UTF-8

Does your container set UTF-8 as page encoding? (See generated page properties). If it does, you don't need to set filter, the browser would submit the form back in UTF-8.

Comment: Browsers usually don't send encoding when submitting a form and servlet container assumes that it's `ISO-8859-1`, so filter is the only right solution in this case.

Comment: Generated page contains the line <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

But, as I mentioned, no success without a filter.

If you think the transformation process is kind of precey, what's the better solution in this case?

Comment: Browsers do send encoding -- the same as the original encoding of the page was, or UTF-8. Otherwise how us, non-Latin1-people, would submit our pity multibyte forms? :D

Comment: @Bar, trace HTTP requests (use FireBug or TamperData for Firefox, for instance) and see what's coming from and goes to server. Check out headers for Content-Transfer-Encoding.